# If $\sum a_n$and$\sum b_n$diverge, can$\sum \min\{a_n,b_n\}$converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Do there exist sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ satisfying all of the following properties?

- $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$
- $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are both decreasing
- $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both diverge
- $\sum\min\{a_n,b_n\}$ converges

Comment: "can it" and "does it" are very different questions — "does it" usually implies that it *always* converges; "can it" just means find an example where it is true.

Comment: what if $\sum_n a_{2n}$ and $\sum_n b_{2n+1}$ both converge and $\sum_n a_{2n+1}$ and $\sum_n b_{2n}$  both diverge ?

Comment: @ElliotG Thank you, I will make my question clearer

Comment: Yes.  What if you make $\min[a_n,b_n]$ as any decreasing sequence you like that has a convergent sum, say, $\min[a_n,b_n] = 2^{-n}$, and then oscillate in your definition of $a_n$ and $b_n$, making one relatively flat, then the other?  So $a_n$ achieves the min for a while while $b_n$ essentially stays the same, then vice versa.

Comment: Anyway, if this is a homework problem, that should be a pretty good hint.

Comment: @Michael this is not a homework.  Since I want {an} and {bn} to be decreasing, then how to oscillate them?

Comment: What is the context of the problem?

Comment: Note that you can replace the "decreasing" constraint with "non-increasing" to make the solution simpler, then just perturb the solution a bit to get both $a_n$ and $b_n$ decreasing.  That is why I said "relatively flat" instead of "flat".

Comment: @Michael I know what you mean, but I not sure this will make {an} and {bn} diverge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35479/discussion-between-michael-and-jerry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Oops. Looking at the comments I see this is exactly what Michael has been suggesting. Sorry - these things happen.

---

Yes.

Say $1=N_1<N_2<\dots$. Define $a_n$ and $b_n$ like so: Assume $N_j\le n<N_{j+1}$.

If $j$ is odd set $a_n=1/n^2$, $b_n=1/N_j^2$.

If $j$ is even set $a_n=1/N_j^2$, $b_n=1/n^2$.

Then $\min(a_n,b_n)=1/n^2$. A little head-scratching shows that both sequences are decreasing. And it's clear that if we take each $N_{j+1}-N_j$ large enough then both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ diverge (for example if $N_{j+1}-N_j>N_j^2$).

(I'm assuming that decreasing means non-increasing. You could easily jiggle the above a little to get strictly decreasing sequences.)